# Reporting and report generation for a web application (nodeJS + angularjs)

Tags: web-apps, node.js, reporting, angularjs

We are developing a web based business solutions using AngularJS + NodeJS with support for either MSSQL or MYSQL database. The product will be installed at client premises and run in an intranet environment.

We need a solution with the following requirements:

1. The developer builds standard reports that are embedded in our solution and deployed at client premises.
2. End users can also create their own reports.

We have identified ActiveReports and Stimulsoft report solutions. Did anyone use one of these or any other reporting tool for a web application ?

Comment: I am watching this question eagerly, as I would like something similar :-)  Do you need something free, or do you have a budget? Can you elaborate a bit more on what sort of reports? Or do you want the possibility to access any column of any table in any configuration? Also, should these reports be generated client side or server side? Do you need any export facilities (PDF, JPEG, CSV ...) Just tables, or charts (which kind?), maps/heat maps/tree maps?

Comment: Do you have URLs for those which you have tried? The first Google hit for ActiveReports says that it is for .NET, which hardly seems to fit with AngularJs. Same for Stimulsoft report  - am I missing something? Or are just looking for an AngularJs solution with similar functionality?

Comment: Hi @Mawg we are looking for free or paid solution (no fixed budget in mind). The reports we need range from charts to lists, to custom reports such as invoices... The exports options required are the most popular ones as you mentionned (PDF, XLS, CSV, Word, ...)

Comment: Stimulsoft have a reports.js option which seems to be applicable/suited for node.js and angularjs [http://www.stimulsoft.com/en/products/reports-js]

Comment: That looks Ok , but costs $700 per license. What is a license? Developer? end user? Also, it is a JS solution - **not** AngulrJs, so you won't get two way data binding out of the box, which is a major hassle.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29936269/which-is-the-best-reporting-tool-in-angular-js-along-with-nodejs

Comment: Is there another alternative? I am on the same situation.
I am developing an application for curreny exchanges.
I am thinking about 2 options: 1) create the report on the Angular side, based on the information (JSON) that Node is providing me. how? I have no idea yet. 2) show on the client side the PDF or HTML that NODE sends. In this case the report should be created on the server side. Any ideas? Regards

Answer (score 2):

[Syncfusion Essential Reports for JS/AngularJS](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejreportviewer) can be used to display Reports in AngularJS applications : [Sample](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/reportviewer/observablebinding/angularjs). It does require a server side .NET based interface.

The report viewer can be embedded in your application and reports can be created by the end users using the [Report Designer](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/report-designer).

The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify. The community license is the full product with no limitations.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Thank you for disclosing your affiliation with Syncfusion.  Recommendations like yours are very welcome here as long as that type of disclosure is made.  Thank you again.

Comment: @Davis Can you confirm is the reporting suit is a part of the community edition? Because I am not able to see any report builder or viewer in the community edition. As you are from Syncfusion, I thought you would be the best person to comment on it.

Comment: @Subbu Report Viewer SDK is included in the Essential Studio Enterprise Edition and that's what is provided as part of the community license https://www.syncfusion.com/sales/products/estudio I will also check and ensure that and get back to you

Comment: @Davis waiting for your confirmation. If it is permitted please share contact details so that we can take this may be over email.